# What is the simplest way to rotate entity with one or two controllers in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I want to grab a box and rotate it with vive-controllers along Y axis, but not enabling any gravity or other physics. I tried to enable aframe-physics-system, but it required gravity. And if I set gravity to 0, all dynamic bodies fly to the ceil.

Comment: Please post what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just found what I was looking for: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/pull/14

Answer (score 0):

Also try the Super Hands component which has grabbing, drag and drop, stretching, and works with Don's physics. https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component